make button in tree view header always show up without selecting a record in odoo 17
in odoo 17 I have a button top of my tree view, I want to set it always visible because I want to open wizard and get data from it, however I haven't found a way to that please help me,
  <record id="view_send_tax_invoices_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">send.tax.invoices.tree</field>
        <field name="model">send.tax.invoices</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="Send Tax Invoices">
                <header>
                    <button name="open_wizard" string="Open Wizard" type="object" class="btn-primary"  />
                </header>
                <field name="invoice_name"/>
                <field name="unique_tax_number"/>
                <field name="date_time_send_issue_bill"/>
                <field name="date_time_create_issue_bill"/>
                <field name="buy_and_sell_rate_difference"/>
                ...
            </tree>

        </field>
    </record>

I tried some property like always_visible="1" but it doesn't work i got  this error : View
error context:
'-no context-'
